# Securing assets in Azure Media Services for mobile-only delivery

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services, azure-media-services

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that uses the Azure SDK, Easy Tables etc. for the bulk of its work. I also have a separate Azure Media Service which hosts and streams video to this app.

The video contains material that is organization-specific, and should not be accessible in any other way than through the app. There is no Azure AD or anything to rely on for authentication, it's as simple as "if client is the app, it can see the video."

What is the simplest way to lock this down in the way I described? Can I do it via the App Service or via Media Service settings somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-configure-asset-delivery-policy. It describe how you can restrict delivery of asset.

Assume you have dynamically encrypted media asset served through your mobile app. In order to play your video, video player need to fetch content key. You can     configure through code who will be able to get content key to decrypt content. Your app will issue JWT token with required set of claims and Azure media service wil validate this token and will return key for player.
Article http://gtrifonov.com/2015/01/03/jwt-token-authentication-in-azure-media-services-and-dynamic-encryption/ describe this flow in more details.

Comment: Thanks George! I came across some of these articles already but my knowledge here is very limited. So I have to encrypt the asset in order to secure it? The problem is that I don't have Azure AD available to issue the token.

Comment: You can issue a JWT token yourself by your back-end service, so AAD is not a requirement. The way it works is that media service is aware about how your sign your token and able verify its signature. If you signing with symmetric encryption, key needs to be uploaded to Azure Media services. You can also use asymmetric algorithm, then you need to instruct Azure Media Service about location of public key (http://gtrifonov.com/2015/06/07/using-json-web-keys-from-openid-connect-discovery-spec-to-work-with-jwt-token-authentication-in-azure-media-services/).

Comment: If you take a look at http://aka.ms/zumobook - it contains information on custom APIs that can be used to issue the token.  How you validate whether the app is the right app is up to you.  In general, you can't say for sure that it's the app - the app is out in the wild, so any secret embedded in the app is also out in the wild.